# Prove $1 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 \leq \cos x$ using Maclaurin series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to prove the following inequality using Maclaurin series (for all $\mathbb{R}$).

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 \leq \cos x$$

I have tried:

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{\sin c}{5!} x^5 \geq 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} =  1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{5} \right)$$

$c \in (0, x)$

But the last term is not greater than $0$ for $x > 5$.

Do I have to take into account the whole Maclaurin series?

Comment: Note that $1-\frac12 x^2 \leq -1$ for $x \geq 2$ and $\cos x \geq -1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Maclaurin expansion for cosine with the Lagrange form of the remainder you have that:
$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 + \dotsm + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2} \cos \xi_x$$
with $\xi_x$ an unknown point between $0$ and $x$. In particular, for $n=0$:
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}\cos\xi_x\geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$
for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is another possible approach to compare with.

The proposed inequality is equivalent to

\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} \leq \cos(x) & \Longleftrightarrow 1 - \cos(x) \leq \frac{x^{2}}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \leq \frac{x^{2}}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \leq \frac{x^{2}}{4}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right| \leq \frac{|x|}{2}
\end{align*}
which is true indeed for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If $\left| x \right| > 2$, then $1 - \frac {1}{2} {x}^{2} < - 1$. Since $\cos \left( x \right) \ge - 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb {R}$, $\left| x \right| > 2$ implies $\cos \left( x \right) > 1 - \frac {1}{2} {x}^{2}$. Below we assume that $\left| x \right| \le 2$.

Recall
$$
\cos \left( x \right) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{k}}{\left( 2 k \right)!} {x}^{2 k}.
$$
So
$$
\cos \left( x \right) - \Big( 1 - \frac {1}{2} {x}^{2} \Big) = \sum_{k \ge 2} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{k}}{\left( 2 k \right)!} {x}^{2 k}.
$$
Now, we separate the series into two, one with $k \mapsto 2 k$ and the other with $k \mapsto 2 k + 1$. Consequently,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 2} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{k}}{\left( 2 k \right)!} {x}^{2 k}
& = \sum_{k \ge 1} \bigg( \frac {{x}^{4 k}}{\left( 4 k \right)!}  - \frac {{x}^{4 k + 2}}{\left( 4 k + 2 \right)!} \bigg) \\
& = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac {{x}^{4 k}}{\left( 4 k \right)!} \, \bigg( 1 - \frac {\left( 4 k \right)!}{\left( 4 k + 2 \right)!} {x}^{2} \bigg).
\end{align}
$$
The series is zero if $x = 0$. That is trivial. Assume that $x \neq 0$. Since $\left| x \right| \le 2$, we derive
$$
\begin{align}
1 - \frac {\left( 4 k \right)!}{\left( 4 k + 2 \right)!} {x}^{2}
& \ge 1 - 4 \cdot \frac {\left( 4 k \right)!}{\left( 4 k + 2 \right)!} \\
& = 1 - \frac {4}{\left( 4 k + 1 \right) \left( 4 k + 2 \right)} = \frac {{\left( 4 k \right)}^{2} + 3 \cdot 4 k - 2}{\left( 4 k + 1 \right) \left( 4 k + 2 \right)},
\end{align}
$$
but
$$
{\left( 4 k \right)}^{2} + 3 \cdot 4 k - 2 \ge {8}^{2} + 3 \cdot 8 - 2 > 0
$$
for all $k \ge 2$.

Thus, we conclude
$$
\boxed {\cos \left( x \right) > 1 - \frac {1}{2} {x}^{2}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb {R} \setminus \{ 0 \}.}
$$
Trivially, $\cos \left( 0 \right) = 1 - \frac {1}{2} \cdot {0}^{2}$. I hope this helps.